# Oracle return rows only if all join conditions match

Tags: sql, oracle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bab93d

See the SQL Fiddle example... I have Customers, Tags, and a mapping table. I am trying to implement customer search by tags, and it has to be an AND search. The query is passed a list of tag identifiers (any number), and it has to return only customers that have ALL the tags.

In the example I have used an IN operator, but that corresponds to an OR search and doesn't solve my problem. What should the query look like to be an AND search?

```
select
  *
from
  customer c
  inner join customer_tag ct on ct.customer_id = c.customer_id
where
  ct.tag_id in (1, 2);
```

This returns both customers, but only the first customer is tagged with tag 1 and 2.

Comment: Do you know how many tags beforehand? If you know that you must match X tags you can add that to your logic

Comment: Well, the user picks the tags, so the query itself doesn't know. But it can count how many were passed to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use correlated subquery to get list of all customers:

```
SELECT  *
FROM  customer c
WHERE c.customer_ID IN
(
     SELECT customer_id
     FROM customer_tag ct
     WHERE ct.customer_id = c.customer_id
       AND ct.tag_id IN (1,2)
     GROUP BY customer_id
     HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tag_id) = 2
);
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/IDLR31462)**</kbd>

It is easy to extend just:

```
WHERE ct_tag IN (1,2,3)
...
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tag_id) = 3
```

Comment: All answers solve the problem, thanks guys :) Accepting this one because it was first.

Answer (score 3):

`JOIN` version:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM  customer c
JOIN (SELECT customer_id
      FROM customer_tag
      WHERE tag_id IN (1,2)
      GROUP BY customer_id
      HAVING MAX(tag_id) <> MIN(tag_id)) ct ON c.customer_id = ct.customer_id
```

If you have more than 2 different values, use `COUNT DISTINCT` instead, like this:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM  customer c
JOIN (SELECT customer_id
      FROM customer_tag
      WHERE tag_id IN (1,2,3)
      GROUP BY customer_id
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tag_id) = 3) ct ON c.customer_id = ct.customer_id
```

Comment:  I agree with this solution. But how will you generate `having` clause for more values like `IN (1,2,3)`?

Comment: So it is basically like my version. Just `IN` changed with `JOIN` :)

Comment: @lad2025, pretty much the same, but I have a JOIN, which may be optimized differently (depending on dbms.)

Comment: First query returns the customer even if they don't have the tag `(1,2,3)`. The second query works, but I had to add a count for the number of tag identifiers instead of a specific number.

Comment: @Edgar, the first one works only for two different tag values, e.g. (1,2).

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

```
SELECT *
FROM customer c
WHERE 
  2 = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ct.tag_id) 
       FROM customer_tag ct 
       WHERE ct.customer_id = c.customer_id AND ct.tag_id IN (1, 2));
```

The `2 = ...` part should be adjusted according to the number of tags you are trying to search for.

---

Alternative solution - correlated subqueries can have poor performance, so you could join in a table like this

```
SELECT c.*
FROM customer c
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ct.customer_id
    FROM customer_tag ct
    WHERE ct.tag_id IN (1, 2)
    GROUP BY ct.customer_id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ct.tag_id) = 2
  ) ct ON ct.customer_id = c.customer_id;
```

Comment: @Edgar I've added a faster solution that doesn't use correlated subqueries. Check it out if you want.

Comment: Thanks for the extra solution.

Comment: Why not a regular `INNER JOIN`? Then you can skip the `WHERE` clause. - Just like my answer!

Comment: @jarlh ahh you're right, dunno what I was thinking.

Answer (score 1):

Extending the other answers, I will add a version where you don't need to count the tags nor list them twice:

```
WITH tgs as(
   select distinct tag_id
   from Tags
   where tag_id in (1, 2, 3, 4) --modify only here
) 
SELECT c.*
FROM  customer c
JOIN (SELECT customer_id
      FROM customer_tag
      WHERE tag_id in (select tag_id from tgs)
      GROUP BY customer_id
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tag_id) = (select count(*) from tgs)
     ) ct ON c.customer_id = ct.customer_id
```

If the tables are rightly normalized(and have pks, etc) you can remove the `distinct` keywords.

Comment: Cool, hadn't written SQL for so long I had forgotten about `WITH`.